# iOS Upload a file via php to a Webserver using Post, how can you get the status?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, progress-bar

So I am uploading an image from an iDevice to a webserver using PHP. Can I somehow get the status of the Upload (in order to fill a progress bar)

This is my iDevice-side code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.bild, 90);

NSString *urlString = @"myurl";
NSLog(urlString);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"dernamedesbildes.jpg\"\r\n"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[conn start];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are using UIProgressview:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
     progressView.progress = (float)totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
 }
```